# Variance of sum of functions of independent random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, independence, variance

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are data from iid sample.
We know that $$V\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right)=nV(X)$$

I'm wondering that if we have a function $h$, can we say that $V\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}h(X_i)\right)=nV(h(X))$?

My reasoning is that they are because if $X,Y$ independent, then $h(X),h(Y)$ are also independent. So can apply equation $1$ with the mapped variables.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. (Assuming all the variances are well-defined: $h(X)$ might not have a finite variance, or even an expectation, even when $X$ does.)